# Limit return data for 7 days

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this table which I use to store events

```
CREATE TABLE EVENT(
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  SOURCE VARCHAR2(50 ),
  TYPE VARCHAR2(50 ),
  EVENT_DATE DATE,
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(100 )
)
/
```

I use this query to get the results for all types of events

```
dbRequest.setPreparedStatement("SELECT "
            + " COUNT(*) \"ALL\","
            + " COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Critical' THEN 1 END) \"CRITICAL\", "
            + " COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Info' THEN 1 END) \"INFO\", "
            + " COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Warning' THEN 1 END) \"WARN\", "
            + " COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Error' THEN 1 END) \"ERROR\" "
            + " FROM "
            + " EVENT");
```

How I can modify the query to get the rows only for last 7 days?
Also for some reason the query is not working with low capital data.

Answer (score 2):

```
dbRequest.setPreparedStatement("SELECT "
            + " COUNT(*) \"ALL\","
            + " COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Critical' THEN 1 END) \"CRITICAL\", "
            + " COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Info' THEN 1 END) \"INFO\", "
            + " COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Warning' THEN 1 END) \"WARN\", "
            + " COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Error' THEN 1 END) \"ERROR\" "
            + " FROM "
            + " EVENT"
            + " WHERE EVENT_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)-7");
```